# Node sass http error, I can't install node-sass on my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sass, node-sass

Recently I formated my computer and install a new windows version, after this update I'm facing the message below error, How can I fix it?

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

```
  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
```

or configure npm proxy via

```
  npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

Comment: same for me today

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in my project.
What I did:

1. Deleted package-lock.json
2. ran command "npm install"

and my issue was fixed.